# Trouble in redirecting page in nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am working on a nodejs application in which main js file controlling states is

```
angular.module('dreamflow', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider',
        function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard', {
                url: '',
                name: 'dashboard',
                templateUrl: '/browser/views/dashboard.html'
            })
            .state('dashboard.processCreation', {
                url: '/processCreation',
                name: 'processCreation',
                parent: 'dashboard',
                templateUrl: '/browser/views/processCreation.html'
            })
            .state('dashboard.formCreation', {
                url: '/formCreation',
                name: 'formCreation',
                parent: 'dashboard', //mandatory
                templateUrl: '/browser/views/formCreation.html'
            });
    }
]);
```

I am working on page **processCreation**. where i am creating a process and then i have to redirect to **formCreation page**  for this i am using

```
$location.url = ('/formCreation');
```

but it is not able to redirect it?

Comment: When do you want your page to redirect. Also if $location service not working, try using $state.go

Comment: Can you reach it when you go there by hand?

Comment: yes. got it using $state.go().  thanx guys.

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh You may wanna "upgrade" your comment to an official that ashishkumar148 can mark it as the "accepted" answer. I'll upvote too.